# Creation of wso2 data service with everyone option (Alllowed user roles)

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I am using wso2 esb 4.0.3.
After creating data service in wso2 esb 4.0.3. with stored procedure, it work's perfectly but when i am choosing Allowed user roles as everyone and giving security as everyone it's giving error.

Error:

```
<soapenv:Fault xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soapenv:Code>
      <soapenv:Value>axis2ns6:UNKNOWN_ERROR</soapenv:Value>
   </soapenv:Code>
   <soapenv:Reason>
      <soapenv:Textxml:lang="en-US">                                                        DS Fault Message: Error setting user roles DS Code:   
UNKNOWN_ERROR Nested Exception:- java.lang.NullPointerException </soapenv:Text>
   </soapenv:Reason>
   <soapenv:Detail>
      <axis2ns5:DataServiceFault xmlns:axis2ns5="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">DS Fault Message: Error setting user roles DS Code: UNKNOWN_ERROR Nested Exception:- java.lang.NullPointerException </axis2ns5:DataServiceFault>
   </soapenv:Detail>
</soapenv:Fault>
```

Please help me on this.

Thanks,
Saurabh Suman

Answer (score 0):

Sounds strange, but anyways, if you are trying to allow everyone to use the data service that you created it works well if you just don't check the "everyone" nor the "admin" checkbox. Give it a try like this.

Comment: yes Jose..By doing like that data service is running perfectly.